# C access to first letter in struct

Tags: c

I would like to write the first letter of "name" but I get an error **"Access violation reading location 0x0000004D"** I don't know what I'm doing wrong? From what I found out, `start[0].name` is a char pointer?

```
struct test {
    int PESEL;
    struct {
        char name[12];
        char name2[12];
        char lastname[12];
    };
};
```

```
test start[3] = { {6236231234, {"John", "Lewo", "Komors"}},
                  {5125124362, {"Ery", "Testo", "Mocny"}},
                  {7844323412, {"Alex", "Mozna", "Ciemny"}}
};
printf("%s", (start[0].name)[0]); // I want the answer to be J
```

Comment: Use `%c` to print a single character, and `%s` to print a string. `start[0].name` is a string, and `start[0].name[0]` is a char.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thank you this actually solves my problem.

Comment: A side note: in this example, you have to use `char*` because text string is not copied into `char[12]` as you may expect.

Comment: Those numbers are probably to big to fit in an `int` and anonymous structs are a GCC extension so don't use them if you want to be portable. Turn on more warnings. Suggestion: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -pedantic-errors`

Answer (score 2):

Change your print statement to the following -

```
printf("%c", start[0].name[0]);
```

The output will be `J`

The problem was with the format specifier, you want to print a character, so the appropriate specifier will be `%c` not `%s` which stands for a string.